# not able to see oracle services in windows services after upgrading to win 8.1

Tags: oracle11g, windows-8.1

I had oracle 11g database installed on my machine (OS win8). It was working fine. This week I upgraded my laptop from win 8 to 8.1. Now I am not able see oracle database services in windows services. Consequently I am not able to start oracle and connect to DB.

Tried couple of things like

```
>oradim -STARTUP -SID ORCL

DIM-00011: The specified service does not exist.
O/S-Error: (OS 1060) The specified service does not exist as an installed servic
e.
```

Is there any way to start the oracle ? or Do I need to re-install the database ?

Kindly let me know if you have some idea about this.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I just had the same problem with Postgres 9.3. I upgraded to Win 8.1 on my workstation and the postgres services disappeared. I re-ran the installer and the services re-appeared, but this service-disappears-on-8.1-upgrade problem appears to be widespread..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello we were having the same issues after the 8.1 upgrade & Managed to resolve (Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0)
The procedures we listed below with the post should help you as well.

http://windows7bugs.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/oracle-services-disappear-from-windows-services-panel-after-upgraded-to-windows-8-1/

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Registry cleaner (System Mechanic 14.5) did it to me (caused the Oracle listener service to be removed from Windows 7). Still had the listener.ora read somewhere else that using lsntrctl start will fix the problem in this circumstance (where there is a valid listener.ora but no service) by adding the service back in.

Comment: remember to start the lsnrctl from cmd in windows with admin privileges else the service wont be created and an error will throws as Unable to open SCManager