# Oracle service does not exist in Windows service(Toad information: "ORA-12541: TNS: no listener")

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Windows 10 Pro and Oracle. 11.2.0.I have a problem, Oracle service does not exist in Windows service.
I have not used oracle for a long time, and today when I use toad to open Oracle, I was told

> ORA-12541: TNS: no listener

and then I found that Oracle service does not exist in Windows service.

Comment: Is the Oracle database installed on your local machine?

Comment: yes, sure. and it usecd to work!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533791/not-able-to-see-oracle-services-in-windows-services-after-upgrading-to-win-8-1), perhaps of some help.

Comment: Thank you! but i dont have net configuration assistant, my oracle is client, so it is problem of server? thank u

Comment: Did you install server or client on your Windows machine?

Comment: Only client. but it used to work before.Server of oracle is in another place

Comment: If it is an another machine, you should check the service has started or not and check the listener is up and running.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am client, but on my machine there is no service of oracle, and when i connect i was told "ORA-12541: TNS: no listener", so according to you it is problem of server? thank u

Comment: Try doing a `tnsping <your service name>` http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_tnsping_command_example.htm

Comment: written like this "C:\Windows\System32>tnsping GRACELANV8_GRA901m 5

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 13-JUN-2017 12:31:35

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146517/discussion-between-user75ponic-and-martinwang1985).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must delete the old one and create a new one listener

Comment: Thank you! but i dont have net configuration assistant, my oracle is client, so it is problem of server? thank u

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help.
i confirm it's problem of server not client
best regards